# Reusing WPF MVVM Views

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I've inherited an application which uses the view-first MVVMC patern

In the application I've created 2 step process which creates a person and assigns them to a group. To do this I've created a view and corresponding view model (all views have a 1-2-1 relationship with a view model, view models are injected into the View constructor and are registered with the Unity container using the TransientLifetimeManager) called CreatePersonMaster, the view simply contains a region (shown by the dashed line) which sub-views can be loaded into and the view model subscribes to two loosely coupled events, "PersonCreated" and "GroupSelected". The "PersonCreated" event saves a Person entity in a field and the "GroupSelected" event takes the saved Person, creates a Group association and saves them to a database.

This view/view model doesn't do anything until the events get raised so I load the following sub views into my the region.

[image: Create Person Views]

These views/view models fire the events which get handled by the master view.

I also have an edit view where I want to re-use the select group view.

[image: Edit Person Views]

I can do this by subscribing to the appropriate events in the EditPersonMaster view model.

My question really is, is this the appropriate way to do this? Because I'm using loosely coupled events I don't get any feedback into the sub-View/ViewModels if there's an error when creating/reassigning? I could probably fire another "ErrorBlah" event for the inner view/model to handle and update the view.

Is there another way to do this? Composite commands don't seem to fit the bill but maybe I don't understand them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I understood your question: You have persons stored in a database, which have a property/column `group`. In your UI, you want to create persons and assign the group property. Also, you want to be able to edit the group property of existing persons in a different region/page/master. You want to reuse the control for assigning the group. Your controls fire an event, which is handled by the Master in a way that it creates the entries in the database (is that correct?). Your question is whether this is a good approach and what alternatives you have?

I see two options:

**1. Modularize your business logic:**

You could inject a data service into your ViewModels, which could access the database directly. This way you can handle errors etc.. directly where they occur and don't have to pass them through the whole system. If you want to notify other modules of changes on the database (specifying the changed dataset or so), you can do so with a composite event. I think of the PRISM modules more as of complete elements, including UI and business logic and keep communication between them as little as possible.

**2. Keep your business logic central and share it:**

If you want to stick to your architecture, have singleton Model which is injected into the ViewModels. Manage your state in the model and have the ViewModels pick the pieces they want to provide to their view.

Hope I got he point, though...